What is this algebraic variety in $\mathbb{R}^4$?
In $\mathbb{R}^4$, what is the 3-dimensional surface defined by the following equation:
$x_3^2 + x_4^2 + \left( \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2} - a \right)^2 = b^2$
?
$a$ and $b$ are constants.
I am trying to visualize what this 3-dimensional surface looks like in terms of something simpler, perhaps as a product of lower dimensional spheres.
If instead of looking at this in $\mathbb{R}^4$ I was looking at it in $\mathbb{R}^3$ I would have
$x_3^2 + \left( \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2} - a \right)^2 = b^2$
which is the equation of a torus. So I would like to know if the 3-dimensional surface defined by my first equation has some similarly simple interpretation.

Can you please outline where you have the particular problem? (And how is this relevant to physics and not simply off-topic, maybe on-topic in math?)

Is $0<b<a$? If so, you’ll have something diffeomorphic to $S^1\times S^2$.

Thanks. Yes, I was implicitly considering that $0<b<a$.
Can you elaborate on how you arrive at this conclusion, from a mathematician's standpoint? I am a physicist and I already thought that my 3-dim surface was "kinda, maybe" related to $S^1 \times S^2$ but having a hard time convincing myself of this rigorously.

say $sqrt(x_3^2+x_4^2)-a=y$ (note this defines a circle in the $x_3x_4$ plane for each $y>-a$). Then, the equation becomes $x_1^2+x_2^2+y^2=b$. This defines a sphere. If $b<a$, $|y|<a$ so the inequality for the circle is satisfied. So we have a map from our space down to a 2 sphere with fibers at every point being circles. You just need an argument to show whether or not it's the product bundle.

I think if you take the section $x_3=\sqrt{a+y},x_4=0$, then this is a trivialization of the product (you can identify this point on each fiber as $(1,0)$ in the plane and use this to get a map to $S^2\times S^1$ that's a homeomorphism).

Thank you - this is amazing. My first post on stackexchange, but it won’t be the last!

@ToyeshJayaswal I'm assuming in your reply you accidentally swapped the $x_1 x_2$ and $x_3 x_4$ planes relative to what's relevant in my question?
